# Getting Pixel Checksum of Control in AutoIt

Tags: java, automation, autoit, vsphere

I've got a pesky checkbox in a login window (the vSphere Client login window) that causes AutoIt's `controlCommandIsChecked` to always return false regardless of if the box is checked or not.  Thus, I decided to resort to performing a pixel checksum on the checkbox's control to determine if it's checked or not based on the checksum value.  I must be doing something wrong though because it's not computing the checksum of the appropriate area at all.  Here's what I came up with ...

```
AutoItX autoIt = new AutoItX();
String loginWindow = "VMware vSphere Client";

double pchecksum = autoIt.pixelChecksum(autoIt.controlGetPosX(loginWindow, "", "[NAME:checkUsePassthrough]"), autoIt.controlGetPosY(loginWindow, "", "[NAME:checkUsePassthrough]"), +
    autoIt.controlGetPosX(loginWindow, "", "[NAME:checkUsePassthrough]")+autoIt.controlGetPosWidth(loginWindow, "", "[NAME:checkUsePassthrough]"), +
    autoIt.controlGetPosY(loginWindow, "", "[NAME:checkUsePassthrough]")+autoIt.controlGetPosHeight(loginWindow, "", "[NAME:checkUsePassthrough]")));
```

Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong here in capturing the coordinates of the control to compute the pixel checksum?

Comment: ...This seems like a terrible idea. Why not just debug why your checkbox isn't working, instead of building this entirely new solution?

Comment: @QPaysTaxes I didn't design the software, it's just Sphere Client. Thus, nothing about the checkbox itself can be changed.

Comment: You can be using a checkbox improperly even when you didn't write the code. Make sure you're using it correctly before attempting a complicated workaround.

Comment: Can you post how you use the `controlCommandIsChecked` as well? It might be easier to be fixed and help you out...